# Cuando doy clic sobre un botón submit hace la acción una única vez y deja de funcionar

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

Estoy haciendo una pequeña página web donde tengo un CRUD normal, lo estoy haciendo con JSP, la ayuda de beans, el patrón de diseño DAO y me conecto a MySQL (sé que es muy anticuado, pero es lo que pidieron en la universidad). Todo funciona bien, el CRUD funciona perfecto, yo tengo un submit que tiene 4 diferentes valores, dependiendo de la acción que escoja: Registrar, Modificar, Eliminar, MostrarDatos. Cuando doy clic al Submit se ejecuta la acción y todo funciona bien, pero si supongamos, yo inserto una vez y quiero volver a insertar, me toca volver al proyecto, compilarlo y ejecutarlo nuevamente para que funcione, ya que deja de funcionar, no sale ningún error ni nada, simplemente deja de funcionar. Les voy a dejar el código JSP que tengo.

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <center><article id="me" class="panel">
        <form name="AddUsuarios" action="BeanAdminUsuarios.jsp" method="post" target="add" onsubmit="return formulario(this)">        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><B>Cédula</B><input id="cedula" name="cedula" type="text"  class="text" required="true" /> </td>
                            <td><B>Nombre</B> <input id="nombres"  name="nombres" type="text" class="text" required="true"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><B>Apellido</B> <input id="apellidos" name="apellidos" type="text"  class="text"  required="true"/>   </td>               
                            <td><B>Dirección</B> <input id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" class="text" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><B>Usuario</B> <input id="usuario"  name="usuarior" type="text" title="Usuario" class="text" required="true"/></td>
                            <td><B>Contraseña</B> <input id="contrasena"  name="contrasenar" type="password"  title="Contrasena" class="text" required="true" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                                    
                    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrarse"  class="button"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form><iframe  name="add" width="250" height="250"></iframe>
    </article></center>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <form name="eliminarUser" action="BeanAdminUsuarios.jsp" method="post" target="eli">
        <div class="5grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u">
                    Ingrese la cédula del usuario a eliminar
                    <br>
                    <input id="codigoEliminar" name="codigoEliminar" type="text" title="cédula" class="text"  />
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Eliminar" class="button" />
        </div>
    </form><iframe  name="eli" width="250" height="250"> </iframe>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <form name="modificarUser" action="FrmModificarUsuarios.jsp" target="mod" method="post">
        <div class="5grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u"> 
                    Ingrese el nombre de usuario que desea modificar
                    <br>
                    <input id="usuarioModificar" name="usuarioModificar" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" class="text" required="true" />                                
                </div> 
                <br>                          
            </div>     
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar" class="button" />
        </div>                
    </form><iframe  name="mod" width="1000" height="1000"> </iframe>
</div>
<div>
```

Este me llama al BeanAdminUsuarios que tiene el siguiente código.

```
 <jsp:useBean id="beanUsuarios" scope="session" class="modelo.DAOUsuarios">
    <jsp:setProperty name="beanUsuarios" property="*" />
    <%
        //Se trae el valor que tiene el submit(botón) y dependiendo de ello se hace una funcionalidad.
        String valorSubmit = (String) request.getParameter("submit");
        if (valorSubmit.equals("Registrarse")) { 
            //Se cargan los atributos para un usuario.
            beanUsuarios.setCedula(request.getParameter("cedula"));
            beanUsuarios.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombres"));
            beanUsuarios.setApellido(request.getParameter("apellidos"));
            beanUsuarios.setDireccion(request.getParameter("direccion"));
            beanUsuarios.setUsuario(request.getParameter("usuarior"));
            beanUsuarios.setContrasena(request.getParameter("contrasenar"));
            //Se valida si el usuario fue insertado o no.
            if (beanUsuarios.insertarUsuario()== true) {
                out.println("Se ha registrado correctamente");
            } else {
                out.println("No se insertó el cliente");
            }              
        } else if (valorSubmit.equals("Eliminar")) {
            beanUsuarios.setCedula(request.getParameter("codigoEliminar")); 
            if (beanUsuarios.eliminarUsuario()) {
                out.print("Se ha Eliminado correctamente");
            } else {
                out.print("No se pudo eliminar");
            }
        }
            else if (valorSubmit.equals("Buscar")) {
            out.print("Se entró a Buscar");                  
            beanUsuarios.setCedula(request.getParameter("codigoModificar"));
        } 
        else if (valorSubmit.equals("Modificar")) {
            beanUsuarios.setCedula(request.getParameter("cedulaMod"));
            beanUsuarios.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombresMod"));
            beanUsuarios.setApellido(request.getParameter("apellidosMod"));
            beanUsuarios.setDireccion(request.getParameter("direccionMod"));
            beanUsuarios.setUsuario(request.getParameter("usuarioMod"));
            beanUsuarios.setContrasena(request.getParameter("contrasenaMod"));                       
            if (beanUsuarios.modificarUsuario()) {
                out.print("Se ha Modificado correctamente");
            } else {
                out.print("No se pudo Modificar");
            }
        }         

    %>
</jsp:useBean>
```

No tengo idea de qué estará afectando el proyecto para que no funcione como debería, o si me falta algún concepto o qué. Es de aclarar que así yo refresque la página sigue sin funcionar, me toca compilar y volver a ejecutar para que nuevamente tome alguna de las acciones.

Comment: No tengo mucho conocimiento de JSP, pero una vez que haces un insert, update, delete, select cierras la conexión de la base de datos?

Comment: Hola. Si, inmediatamente cierro la conexión a la base de datos. Cada vez que voy a hacer un proceso abro y cierro la base de datos.

Comment: No he trabajado con `<jsp:useBean>` y no recomiendo el trabajo con scriptlets, por lo que no sabría a ciencia cierta indicarte dónde está el problema. De momento, necesitaría ver el stacktrace del error que te sale cuando dices que la aplicación "deja de funcionar" o que describar más qué es lo que sucede. ¿Acaso ya no se muestra la página donde están los datos, no se refrescan los resultados, te salta un mensaje de error "extraño"?

Comment: No sale ningún error, en el log tampoco hay una traza diferente, simplemente deja de funcionar el botón submit. Si inserto un dato a la base de datos, inserta bien y si en ese mismo momento quiero ir a modificar un dato, ya no me permite hacer nada, cuando le doy clic en el botón nuevamente, no hace nada, como sino tuviese funcionamiento.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la url de tu página? ¿Puedes ver el HTML generado de la página una vez que has hecho el primer submit si es que los formularios tienen algo en el action? Asimismo, puedes probar presionando la tecla F12 en Firefox/Chrome y en el tab Red (o Network) revisar si cuando haces submit realmente se envía algo al servidor, en caso que no se envíe nada es un problema en el cliente que muestras luego de realizar la primera acción.

Comment: cuando inspecciono no aparece nada fuera de lo normal. Como te digo, cuando lo hago la primera vez funciona perfecto, pero si quiero repetir la acción o aplicar otra deja de funcionar, es como si el botón estuviese vacío, sin nada por hacer.

Comment: debuguea mas detalladamente, por ejemplo pone mensajes y que te muestre por consola a cada parte para saber hasta donde llega

Comment: Eso he hecho, tengo sout para cuando entra a cada uno de los métodos, pero simplemente deja de funcionar el botón. no hace ninguna acción

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de buscar información y de pensar en qué estaba fallando, encontré el error; Cuando se utilizan beans, también se define un ciclo de vida, en lo cual yo estaba definiendo un ciclo de vida "session" que duraba durante todo el tiempo que tuviese en ejecución el proyecto y por ello el bean no podía atender otras solicitudes. La solución fue cambiar el ciclo de vida del bean a tipo "request" así funciona cada que se hace una solicitud.

Estaba así:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="beanUsuarios" scope="session" class="modelo.DAOUsuarios">
```

Quedó así:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="beanUsuarios" scope="request" class="modelo.DAOUsuarios">
```